# aws_network_interface_sg_attachment module on adding new SG , destroying existing SG

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

AWS instance , Elastic Network Interface (ENI) has existing security group (SG_main).
Adding new SG (sg-01) using aws_network_interface_sg_attachment resource.
sg-01 is getting added , SG_main has no affect on it.

Adding another sg-02 using aws_network_interface_sg_attachment resource.
destroy's sg-01 , attaches sg-02 and SG_main(no change).

Is there any other module don't destroy existing SG or Is there any other way to achieve this.

Input variable -

```
sg_attachment = [
 {
    attach_security_group_id    = "sg-01"
 }
]
```

Input variables are given in above form , as I was planning to give multiple values later like below.
["sg-01","sg-02","sg-03"] -> will be mapped with EC2[0]
["sg-04","sg-05"] -> will be mapped with EC2[1]
.. like wise.

```
sg_attachment = [
 {
    attach_security_group_id    = ["sg-01","sg-02","sg-03"]
 },
 {
    attach_security_group_id    = ["sg-04","sg-05"]
 }
]
```

resource block

```
resource "aws_network_interface_sg_attachment" "sg_attachment" {
  count = length(var.sg_attachment) != 0 ? length(var.sg_attachment) : 0
  security_group_id    = var.sg_attachment[count.index].attach_security_group_id
  network_interface_id = aws_instance.EC2[count.index].primary_network_interface_id
}
```

Comment: Do you have any TF code demonstrating the issue?

Comment: updated TF code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any other way to achieve this.

You would have to use [aws_network_interface](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/network_interface) data source to query for the existing  [security_groups](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/network_interface#security_groups) for your ENI.

```
data "aws_network_interface" "existing_sgs" {
  count = length(aws_instance.EC2)
  id = aws_instance.EC2[count.index].primary_network_interface_id
}
```

Once you have `existing_sgs` you would have to [concat](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/concat.html) them with the new ones. Otherwise, the old ones get replaced with the new ones as you already observed.

Comment: security_group_id in the resource "aws_network_interface_sg_attachment" block only takes string and not a list, how to over come that.

Comment: @AbhishekSolanki You have to use count or for_each to iterate over your list and create individual `aws_network_interface_sg_attachment`

Comment: @AbhishekSolanki How did it go? I see you made question, so this old question is still unresolved?

Comment: Hi Marcin , it worked, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @AbhishekSolanki No problem. Glad it worked.